# When i compile aspectj file with axis2 service i found this error.Do anybody know what should i do

Tags: java, glassfish, apache-axis, aspect, netbeans6.5

This Web axisService has deployment faults
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:273) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:468) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceGroupBuilder.populateServiceGroup(ServiceGroupBuilder.java:101) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:109) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:143) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283) at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1023) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4917) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5324) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:353) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:989) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:973) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1627) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1232) at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:182) at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:278) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeModuleDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:1005) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleModuleDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:992) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:470) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:280) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:298) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.deploy(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:584) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:381) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:364) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477) at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836) at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90) at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304) at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:174) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.invokeDeploymentService(AutoDeployer.java:583) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployJavaEEArchive(AutoDeployer.java:564) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:495) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:270) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployControllerImpl$AutoDeployTask.run(AutoDeployControllerImpl.java:374) at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512) at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:96) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:277) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ... 68 more

Answer (score 0):

It is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError". That means particular class can not be found in the classpath. Did you put the required libraries in the "lib" folder?.
Check, the required jars are at axis2 classpath or not

Comment: i have given the path for aspectjrt.jar in the classpath. also i have loaded the aspectj_runtime in the library. Still the error exists